# How to animate a background size using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to animate the background of my website so that when the user enters it, the background starts at a size of 60% and goes up until 100% over the course of several seconds.

I tried using animate in jQuery like below, but the console says 'Unexpected token -'. This worked for opacity in another piece of code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.left-content').animate(
    {
        background-size: 100%
    },
    3000);
})
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around `background-size` and `100%`

Comment: well now I get 'object is not a function' and I don't really know why :-?

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded?

Comment: I am positive, don't really know what is the problem. If I delete this script, everything goes back to normal.

Comment: @Radu there's nothing wrong with the code in your question that hasn't been addressed in the answers. If you're having a different problem you're going to have to give more information.

Comment: You could actually lighten the load and use CSS Animations here.

Comment: I have done it using CSS Animations as you say. Then some colleague at work helped me with that function. It works now. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. Missing quotes around 100%
2. JavaScript understands `background-size` as variable `background` minus `variable` size. You shoud use `backgroundSize` instead.

   `$('.left-content').animate({ backgroundSize: '100%' }, 3000);`

With these two corrections, it works. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/YuKj3/

Comment: @Radu, did you check the jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap quotes around `100%`. After that you can either wrap quotes around `background-size` as well:

```
{
    "background-size": "100%"
}
```

...or use camel case:

```
{
    backgroundSize: "100%"
}
```